# Software to Simulate Programming (Which writes text slowly like a human)

Tags: c++, programming, simulation, keyboard

for my school project I want to make a short video about programming.
In the video I want to show how I write code but in faster speed like 3x or 5x with music in the background. But I cant type too fast and clean - is there any software out there where I can input any text and when I click start it will write the Text with a specified speed like I would do but fast and continiously? If it simulates keyboard input I could just let it write the code into a new file and record it.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! It would help if you could state which OS the software shall run on, and how much you'd be willing to spend on it.

Comment: You could also use a video editing program to increase the speed of parts of your video afterwards. Premiere and After Effects, for example, can do that. I think Kdenlive (free and open source) can do that too.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which platform you're on, but if it's Windows, you could use [**AutoHotkey**](https://www.autohotkey.com/) for this.

You can have it open (or activate) your editor or IDE if you like. Then use [`Send`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) to send keystrokes. You can adjust the speed at which it spits out characters using [`SetKeyDelay`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm). You can have it control the mouse too, if you like. Pretty much anything you can do manually, you can do with AutoHotkey.